# VS Code can't resolve module after adding it to path

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, python-import

I'm trying to import a module `controller` that is located in this folder path `C:\Program Files\Webots\lib\controller\python39\controller.py`. My code is located in a different folder `C:\Users\M----\Documents\School\ECE10\Project1\controllers\p1_controller.py` therefore I'm adding the folder location to the path so I can import it as follows:

```
import sys
sys.path.append('C:\Program Files\Webots\lib\controller\python39')

from controller import Robot
```

However, VS code says that it still cannot resolve the module as if it was never imported. I'm not sure if this is a python issue of VS code issue? Any help is appreciated!

[image]

Answer (score 1):

`sys.path.append` can not influence the IntelliSense, although you can run your code successfully the IntelliSense will still prompt the error message.

You need to modify `python.autoComplete.extraPaths` in the settings.json, like this:

```
"python.autoComplete.extraPaths": [
    "C:/Program Files (x86)/Google/google_appengine",
    "C:/Program Files (x86)/Google/google_appengine/lib/flask-0.12"]
```

You can refer to the [official docs](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/editing#_enable-intellisense-for-custom-package-locations) for more detail.